# Where is the login page .phtml file?

Tags: theme, customer, ce-1.8.1.0, login, design

I want to change login page file (some design additional) but I didn't find the file (I think it's login.phtml file, right?) from anywhere!

I changed login.phtml file in base and my custom theme's persistent and customer directories, but nothing happened. How can I find which login.phtml file is correct?

Comment: Never change codes in base directory, create a fallback theme and copy codes from base directory to that fallback theme and modify it.

Comment: Maybe you use an extension which overwrites the default login.phtml?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're unable to locate a `phtml` file it's best to turn on template hints.

1. Disable cache
2. In the backend go to `System` > `Configuration` > `Developer` and fill out your IP
3. Change the scope to website level with the top left dropdown
4. Turn on `Template Path Hints` under `Debug`

In the frontend refresh the page and the path to the login template should be visible.

Answer (score 4):

There's actually two places to look for login file. Older versions stored it in `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/customer/form/login.phtml` and newer ones use persistent catalog `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml`

Also, do yourself a favor and learn how to use template hints as @Sander suggested. There's no hidden catch anywhere -- it really makes your life much, MUCH easier.

Answer (score 2):

Enable template hint for your store view,

1. Go  to `System >Configuration> Advanced >Developer`
2. Switch to Store view from right side `Current Configuration Scope box`.
3. In `Debug > Template Path Hints set as Yes.`